# How to display strings exactly as is in Text views without any special formatting in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, string, swiftui

I'm trying to display my app's version and build number in `X.X.X (X)` format but SwiftUI is automatically formatting the build number into a circle. How do I stop this behavior? I've tried a few string literal methods, but nothing has worked so far.

[image: Screenshot]

```
func versionTextView() -> some View { 
    let appVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
    let buildNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String
    let versionText = "Version \(appVersion) (\(buildNumber))"

    // I've also tried this
    // let versionText = #"Version \#(appVersion) (\#(buildNumber))"#

    return Text(versionText)
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code shown, but you can try `Text(verbatim: versionText)`

Comment: Yep I tried that as well, but it didn't work either

Comment: Have you code any other view around this one ?

Comment: since  `appVersion` and `buildNumber` are `String`, have you tried:  `let versionText = "Version " + appVersion + "(" + buildNumber + ")"`.  Note, 
I can't reproduce your problem either. Do you have a localized string equivalent by any chance?

Comment: @PtitXav Thanks, you made me wonder myself. Turns out that a custom font modifier was causing the issue.